# Поиск значений по последним 5 цифрам в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно по последним 5 цифрам из user найти number и name.

пробовал запрос:
SELECT
t1.user, t2.number, t2.name
FROM t1, t2
where t2.number like '%' + t1.user
LIMIT 100

скрипт висит часами, но ничего не получается. Видимо где-то ошибка.

Comment: Если number - целое число, то для начала надо его конвертировать в строку, а только потом искать через LIKE

Comment: как это сделать ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24723699/6104996

Comment: `.. FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.user = t2.number MOD 100000 ..`

Comment: @Akina Спасибо большое, вроде работает. Можете в двух словах объяснить почему именно MOD 100000 ? почитал описание оператора, но сходу сложно понять все

Comment: Последние 5 цифр числа равны остатку от деления этого числа на 100000. Собственно оператор MOD этот остаток и считает. Я не могу себе даже представить, что тут сложно понять...